# Method name expected c#

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have an event handler, i would like to pass some parameters to the event

like this, that line trigger an error: method name expected

```
   p.Click += new System.EventHandler(P_Click(sender, new MyEventArgs { design = reader1["desig_prd"].ToString(), prix = (float)reader1["prix_prd"] }));
```

my P_Click event

```
public void P_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var args = (MyEventArgs)e;
        string deignation = args.design;
        MessageBox.Show(deignation);
    }
```

and i have class MyEventArgs like this

```
class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string design { get; set; }
    public float prix { get; set; }
}
```

Any help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have access to `reader1` from the `P_Click` method's scope?

Answer (score 4):

You can't pass arguments to your method when you subscribing an event handler.You should just specify the method name:

```
p.Click +=  new EventHandler(P_Click);
```

Or short notation:

```
p.Click +=  P_Click;
```

If you want to trigger this manually and pass some arguments then you should call your method with that arguments:

```
P_Click(this, new MyEventArgs { design = reader1["desig_prd"].ToString(), 
                                prix = (float)reader1["prix_prd"] 
                              });
```

But this is usually a bad practice, (triggering event handler methods manually).Instead use [`PerformClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method after subscribe your event handler and of course create another method for your arguments, and call that method from `P_Click`:

```
p.PerformClick();
```

Comment: `p.Click +=  P_Click;` won't work because `P_Click` doesn't have the proper signature.  He won't be able to fire the event, or provide different arguments to the event handler when it's fired, because he doesn't control the definition of the object that defines/fires the event, nor does that defining class have access to this data to provide when it is fired.

Comment: @Servy if `p` is a `button` yes the method signature is proper.you think it is not a button?

Comment: @Selman22 Right, I was imagining that the method accepted a `MyEventArgs` as the argument, so ignore that part, but the *important* part still remains.  He is in no position to alter how the button is firing the event such that it will provide this data to that handler, nor, if that were in some way possible, would that type have access to this data to provide (nor should it).  The whole solution is nonsensical.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to this

```
 p.Click += new System.EventHandler(P_Click);
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem of how he can access that required data in the click handler.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood how events work.

`p.Click` is the event.

`P_Click` is the event handler.

You don't send the sender and event args - because the event does.
So to hook the event all you need is `p.Click += new System.EventHandler(P_Click);` or event simply `p.Click += P_Click;`

You don't need `MyEventArgs` (at least not for this case), and instead, just calculate these values in the event hadler itself:

```
public void P_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var design = reader1["desig_prd"].ToString();
    var prix = (float)reader1["prix_prd"];
    ...
}
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem of how he can access that required data in the click handler.

Comment: That data is available to him in the click event handler... but I'll edit that

Comment: But that's the whole point, `reader1` isn't in scope in the event handler, only where the handler is being attached.

Comment: Once again you telepathy over TCP/IP skill amaze me... Please read the question, before "determining" what is the point

Comment: I have read the question.  It's quite obvious that this is not a valid solution.  Someone trying to pass information to an event handler simply won't bother if there is no need to pass it.  There very often *is* a need to pass the information to the event handler when adding it, namely in the case where the given data is not in scope within the event handler.  This case is *extraordinary* common, and you're simply ignoring it.

Comment: *You* are assuming that the variable is in scope.  What is your basis for that assumption?  I fully recognize that I am making the assumption that the variable is out of scope.  There is compelling evidence to support that assumption, and I am quite confident.  If you want to make the assumption that the variable is in scope, you should support that assumption.  Making no assumption at all would be to provide a solution that works *regardless* of whether or not the variable is in scope.  You haven't done that.

Comment: What make me think that -is that the event handler is in the same class where the event is hooked. Now, it could be declared in a base class, but this is by far less common than a handler which is declared in the exact same class which hook the event.

Comment: The most common reason for it to be in scope where the event is attached, but not in the definition of the method, would be the case where `reader1` is a local variable, rather than an instance field.

Comment: And the most common reason to create unrelated event-args, and try to pass them to an event handler which is fired from an entirely event, is not understanding events. which would make you assumption unnecessary

Comment: The desire to have an event handler use information provided when the handler is added does *not* demonstrate a lack of understanding of events.  Not knowing the proper way to go about implementing such a desire does, to a point.  In no way does that make the assumption unnecessary.  Once again, you're *assuming* that `reader1` is in scope within the event handler.  What evidence do you have to support that *assumption*?  How do you know that this solution is feasible at all?

Comment: More evidence than you have to assume that he understand events, while  he clearly trying to send the arguments from the hook... But enough assumptions... lets ask him

Comment: Where did you see me say that I felt he understood events?  I specifically said that not knowing how to solve this problem does demonstrate, to a point, a lack of understanding about events.  However, trying to provide arguments to a handler, from the hook, in no possible way demonstrates a lack of understanding of events.  That you think it does demonstrates that *you* have a lack of understanding about events, as it is an entirely reasonable thing to want to do, the author just doesn't know how to go about doing it.

Comment: Once again, you have ignored my request for you to provide evidence to support your assumption.  Apparently you do not have any evidence to support your assumption.  It appears to be a baseless assumption on your part.

Comment: If he do not understand events, this alone can explain why he would try to do that. So your assumption is unnecessary, and redundant . One assumption is always more likely than two assumptions which include the first one. Now, that he lack understanding of event, is not an assumption, because it evident from his code. This is my evidence. Now, where is yours?

Comment: Someone without a solid understanding of events is *far* more likely to attempt what you have in your solution.  Someone who is beginning to grasp events, but is still in the process of learning is likely to try something like what he did.  I'd say he has a stronger grasp on the proper use of events than you do.  Beyond that, your assumption, even if it were to be accepted, in no way invalidates mine.  It is entirely reasonable to consider the case where the variable is no in scope inside of the event handler.  That is a *very* common situation, regardless of the OP's understanding.

Comment: I like it when I frustrating someone to the point he uses ad hominem. Even more, when he start to squirm with seeing "without a solid understanding" as less understanding than "Someone who is beginning to grasp". I believe this conversation is over.

Comment: You do realize that your previous comment was nothing but an ad hominem attack on the OP, do you not?  You also seem to be completely ignoring the fact that the OP's understanding, as I explained before, is not relevant here.  The question is entirely reasonable, you don't address it, and that makes the answer of very poor quality.  You appear to be trying to argue solely for the sake of winning the argument, rather than discussing the actual merits of the answer.

Comment: You should understand what ad hominem is, before using that term (you think you do, as you think you know what others meant, and do - but you don't). as I said before - this conversation is over.

Answer (score 1):

Use a lambda to close over the data that you want to use in your event handler:

```
p.Click += (s, args) => 
    P_Click(reader1["desig_prd"].ToString(), (float)reader1["prix_prd"]);
```